# Java draw to Graphics in own thread, outside EDT?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, paintcomponent, event-dispatch-thread

I am coding a Swing Application, it uses Apache PDFBox to draw a PDF page to the Graphics2D object of a JPanel in the paintComponent method. The drawing takes a while, so when my application needs to display many PDF pages simultaneously, it get's slow and laggy. I know, since the JPanel I draw the PDF page to is part of the GUI, it needs to be drawn in the Event Dispatch Thread. But is there absolutely no possibility to draw each JPanel in an own thread? Like using SwingWorker or so?

*Example code (simplified):*

```
public class PDFPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        int scale = 1;   // (simplified this line)

        g2.setColor(getBackground());
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        try {
            pdfRenderer.renderPageToGraphics(pageNumber, g2, (float) scale, (float) scale);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See also the source code of PDFDebugger (PagePane.java), it uses a SwingWorker. And some tricky stuff to accomodate HiDPI screens.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr oh thanks! The class RenderWorker seems like a good example to start with. It says PDDocument is officially not thread safe, do you think that's a problem when I use it to draw many BufferedImage objects simultaneously?

Comment: They should have several PDDocuments. I.e. each thread should work on its own PDDocument => you'll need more RAM.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr But that means I need to open/read in the same document multiple times, wouldn't that be very bad practice/performance?

Comment: Opening files is usually fast unless they are extremely complex. It's the rendering that is slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `BufferedImage` image field. It has a method `createGraphics()` where you can draw to. Afterward call `Graphics.dispose()` to clean up resources.

Then in `paintComponent` check the availability of the image, for displaying it.

The rendering can be done in a Future, SwingWorker or whatever. You are right that heavy operations should never be done in `paintComponent` especially as it may be called repeatedly.

Better launch the rendering in the constructor, or in your controller.

```
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
    try {
        pdfRenderer.renderPageToGraphics(pageNumber, g2, (float) scale, (float) scale);
    } finally {
        g2d.dispose();
    }
```

Initially width and height are not filled, so better use width and height from the PDF. Also not that a Graphics2D allows scaling; you could easily add zooming.

How to atomically handle passing the rendered image is probably clear.

Comment: First, thank's very much! Nice and simpel solution. I will try it the next days and mark your answer. I'm already scaling, just left it out here. I actually do draw it to BufferedImage in part of my application for another reason, drawback was that the memory usage seems very heavy, because the image must be created with double scale to get a good looking quality of the PDF (seems like a PDFBox Library thing). Otherwise I might buffer the images but not all (some PDFs have hundreds of pages), like 30 or so..